# How to get angular 5 cdn

Tags: angular

I have basic knowledge of angularjs , now i want to learn Angular 5.
I am not want to install node.js for angular 5.
So where to get angular 5 cdn.

```
https://angular.io/
```

Comment: You can play around with Angular here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yapvki

Comment: I want to add angular 5 cdn in php files

Answer (score 2):

Angular 5 has no CDN. You have to install it with npm.

Answer (score 2):

```
Cdn: Angularjs (angular < 2 )
Without cdn install with npm:Angular2,Angular4,Angular5,Angular6 (angular >=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no CDN for angular 5... You have to install angular 5 through cli (or) manually by installing every package... to deal with packages you need node.